# How much grass is enough for the animals in Stardew Valley?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm planning out my farm layout and was wondering... how much grass tiles would be good enough for two 3rd level barn/coops (24 animals)? "Good enough" as in "there's no need to buy hay during warm seasons, nor plant additional patches. they'll be eaten and re-grow in a stable pace".

Is there any sort of formula, or information on how much the grass can grow per day?

---

**EDIT**: while I found no formula, as this subject seems a bit complex (depending on available space besides the grass, where the animals ate, etc), I did found an awesome [Stardew planner](https://stardew.info/planner) that helped me realize there's a LOT of space in the terrain to be left for grass, as you'll certainly not plant it all.

Comment: My obese chickens ate all their grass in front of their coop. I need to now that too.

Comment: As far as I know. livestock eats the grass faster than it can grow. What I did was have a separate patch of grass that was fenced off that I used for generating fodder for the winter. along with resupplying the pasture every few days.

Answer (score 1):

I think each one eats one grass patch per day, so you'll have to make sure 24 new grass patches grows every day. You can put a 2x2 fence around a patch of grass, and the grass inside will be safe from animals. Make 24 "grass preservation stations" and you should have more than enough grass for all the animals.

Comment: That is no different from simply making 24 2x2 patches of grass. Not to mention a 2x2 patch won't make 1 new patch of grass each day, and animals eat more than that anyway.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer If those aren't just guesses your points might make a good answer

Answer (score 1):

The planner you found will probably be the best tool for working this out but to answer the question...
Each animal will consume roughly *the equivilant* of one patch of grass a day, but that will often be from several patches in small amounts, so a single chicken in a field of grass wouldn't eat enough for you to even notice some of the taller grass is now a little shorter.

For larger numbers of animals the measurement is always how much more grass will grow, rather than how much you have and that is all about how much blank space there is for it to grow into. Each individual patch of grass tries to spread in at least one direction each day, but if that tile is occupied by anything it will fail, and not spread. This is a mechanic used for a lot of things in stardew valley.

If you had enough grass that it had a little over 24 open spaces around it most of the time, then it would be enough to consistently feed all your animals, but if you just had 24 patches of grass in one block it would be eaten up very quickly. Try to avoid small fenced in area's of grass for this reason.

Lots of small patches works well without using up much room, or one large patch, even if it is a bit further away, as long as the animals have a clear patch to it.

Source: Buying far to many grass starters without realising how to use them myself, before working out that they all want ample room around them to spread into.